# Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 won't boot

Tags: installation, boot, kernel

I've made 3 USB installers; and none of them have installed? I don't understand what's happening?

Comment: What *does* happen? How are you trying to install? Can you boot from them? Are there error messages. Your question is unanswerable in its current form and might be closed. Please edit your question to expand it with as many potentially relevant details as you can think of. If your question is closed, then after editing it, please comment and/or flag to request it be reopened. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the package from the website is corrupt. Happened to me as well, all i got was a blinking cursor whenever i tried to boot on USB.

If thats what you are facing then Follow these steps-
Search for a torrent for ubuntu(whichever version youve downloaded) and set the download location as the same as the one where your existing zip file(from the ubuntu website) is. Make sure both the file names are the same(the one from the website and the torrent file).

This way when you start your torrent download, your bit torrent client will automatically do a checksum and download only the missing fragments.

[My First Answer so I'm sorry if this was a bit unclear! Let me know if I need to improve upon this for your clarity]